# mySQL Export Excel with concated data

Tags: mysql

I'd like a custom export file from mySQL.

I have a table:

```
name .   number .   class
--------------------------------
name1 .  100 .      1
name2 .  101 .      3
name1 .  100 .      5
```

Now i'd like to export this data into a excel file.
But where it is duplicate number i'd like to concat the class data.
Output from table above would be:

```
name1    100  1 5
name2    101  3
```

The classes should be seperated with whitespace.

Is this possible?

Maby i have to create another table and concat the data in the first step, and later export that table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT name, number,GROUP_CONCAT(class SEPARATOR ' ') FROM table1 GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Looks good, but i should group by number.. becuse it´s uniq.. the names